# How to prevent Chrome from auto suggesting form fields?

Tags: google-chrome

This is not related to autofill fields but to the suggestions that appear when focused on a field. Some fields this makes them completely unusable like in the example image provided. In this example a site's datepicker is blocked by Chrome suggesting previously selected dates.

This feature often blocks me on sites where there are dropdowns under the field especially date pickers or typeahead suggestions. Just because I selected a value in the past does not mean I always want to see those suggestions from Chrome. Is there a way to block these but leave autofill like username/passwords working? It seems they are different enough to be separate.

[Form field blocked by Google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdUWw.png)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

1. Click the 3-dot menu button in the upper right
2. Go to "Settings"
3. Go to "Autofill" on the left
4. Click "Addresses and more"
5. Slide the slider to the left on "Save and fill addresses"

This is the closest option I could find. There might not be a way to turn it off in Google Chrome. If you try the following after doing the above, it will clear the cookies and should prevent the saving of the data between sessions.

1. Click "Privacy and security" on the left
2. Click "Site Settings"
3. Click "Cookies and site data"
4. Slide the slider to the left on "Clear cookies and site data when you quit Chrome"

Comment: The only issue I see is that these aren't autofill. I consider autofill to populate without any user input. On this one, when you focus a field it displays a dropdown over anything else that is a suggestion.